# BIND 9.10.2-P3 won't resolve download.adobe.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I can resolve a domain I've never visited like dog.com below, but ... when I try to resolve download.adobe.com, it fails:

> c:\WINDOWS\system32\dns>nslookup
>     Default Server:  mail.XXX.com
>       Address:  172.16.0.101
>
> dog.com
>   Server:  mail.XXX.com
>   Address:  172.16.0.101
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   Name:    dog.com
>   Address:  168.75.167.164
>
> download.adobe.com
>   Server:  mail.XXX.com
>   Address:  172.16.0.101
>
> mail.XXX.com can't find download.adobe.com: Non-existent domain

---

I notice that if I use an external dns with nslookup, they will resolve it and depending on the external dns, I get different answers like user-att-104-61-56-0.a1953.d.akamai.net or a1953.d.akamai.net both of which resolve to different ips.

I just moved to U-Verse and changed all my ips, but I'm not sure that is the cause as the U-Verse dns used by my modem for wifi can resolve this just fine?

I have the most recent named\zones\root.servers, recursion yes;

It seems like this might have something to do with they way adobe maps that download to different akamai hosts, but ... I'm definitely not a dns guru so I'm out of my depth!!

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: I looked for download in named.log and didn't see anything.  I did a
dig +trace download.adobe.com and here's the very end (can't post it all in a comment):
;; Received 1004 bytes from 192.12.94.30#53(e.gtld-servers.net) in 171 ms

download.adobe.com.     10800   IN      CNAME   download.wip4.adobe.com.
;; Received 75 bytes from 23.61.199.64#53(a7-64.akam.net) in 171 ms

Comment: What I find particularly strange is that your `nslookup` output seems to indicate an `NXDOMAIN` response, which would indicate a successful lookup with a negative result. If something had actually failed during the lookup I would have expected `SERVFAIL` instead.  (I'm not sure if I'm possibly reading too much into the `nslookup` output? I don't ever use `nslookup` myself, is *Non-existent domain* something that will be shown for any other status than `NXDOMAIN`?)

Comment: Regarding `dig +trace` output, here's a point of reference: http://pastie.org/private/iaooe8oaxfggmtezfyfjha  Can you follow the chain of `CNAME`s the same way from there?

Comment: Håkan - my dig looks very similar to yours, except that after adobe.com.              172800  IN      NS      a13-65.akam.net. it ends with download.adobe.com.     10800   IN      CNAME   download.wip4.adobe.com.  adobe-dns-03.adobe.com. to a13-65.akam.net. (that show in yours) are completely missing? Is there a better tool to use to debug, it's been a while since I"ve messed with BIND.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/ka866ihbb0elyc2hrcgpca

Comment: To be clear, I ran multiple `dig +trace` commands (as you can see in the paste) to trace the name from each previous step.

Comment: Yes, but I'm missing the very bottom part of your original dig, as you can see from that pastie I just posted - from adobe-dns-03.adobe.com. to a13-65.akam.net. are missing for me?

Comment: I'm looking at http://pastie.org/private/iaooe8oaxfggmtezfyfjha#81 vs http://pastie.org/private/ka866ihbb0elyc2hrcgpca#55 and I think it looks rather similar for the first command?

Comment: I'm going to have to re-charge my brain a bit as it seems like I'm missing a lot at the very end of the dig?  Let me review a bit and I'll try to get back to this sometime tonight.  Thanks!!

Comment: If you are talking about differences *above* the highlighted lines in my previous comment, I noted that you ran a slightly different command (no `+add`).

Comment: If, on the other hand, you are talking about my output from the additional dig commands after the highlighted line (near the end of the output of the first command), it doesn't look like you ran any more commands after the first one.